# pub generating %LOCALAPPDATA% folder in my dart project root folder

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, dart-pub

**System info.**

```
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 22000) 
Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable) (Tue Dec 14 13:32:21 2021 +0100) on "windows_x64"

Flutter 2.8.1 • channel stable
Framework • revision 77d935af4d (7 weeks ago) • 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
Engine • revision 890a5fca2e
```

**.dart_tool\package_config.json**

```
  "configVersion": 2,
  "packages": [
    {
      "name": "lints",
      "rootUri": "../%25LOCALAPPDATA%25/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/lints-1.0.1",
      "packageUri": "lib/",
      "languageVersion": "2.12"
    },
    {
      "name": "dart_get_set_go_v2",
      "rootUri": "../",
      "packageUri": "lib/",
      "languageVersion": "2.15"
    }
  ],
  "generated": "2022-02-02T20:18:50.045994Z",
  "generator": "pub",
  "generatorVersion": "2.15.1"
}
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMdZK.png)

Whenever I'm trying to create a dart project the pub generator generates and download the packages in the root folder which again breaks the code. I tried creating projects in different places (Users, Desktop, Documents) to check if their was some kind of privilege escalation issue but no avail.